# JWT encrypting payload in python? (JWE)

Tags: python, jwt, jwe, pyjwt, python-jose

According to [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) it should be possible to encrypt the payload/claim, called JWE.

Are there any python libraries out there that support that?

I've checked PyJWT, python-jose and jwcrypto but they all just have examples for signing with `HS256` (JWS).

Sorry if this is totally obvious, but when it comes to things involving crypto I'm extra cautious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both Jose and jwcrypto libraries can do JWE.

For [jose](http://jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
claims = {
'iss': 'http://www.example.com',
'sub': 42,
}
pubKey = {'k':\
           '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n\
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
    }
# decrypt on the other end using the private key
privKey = {'k': 
    '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+\
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
}

encJwt = jose.encrypt(claims, pubKey)
serJwt = jose.serialize_compact(encJwt)
decJwt = jose.decrypt(jose.deserialize_compact(serJwt), privKey)
```

---

For [jwcrypto](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
# algorithm to use
eprot = {'alg': "RSA-OAEP", 'enc': "A128CBC-HS256"}
stringPayload = u'attack at dawn'
E = jwe.JWE(stringPayload, json_encode(eprot))
E.add_recipient(pubKey)
encrypted_token = E.serialize(compact=True)
E = jwe.JWE()
E.deserialize(encrypted_token, key=privKey)
decrypted_payload = E.payload
```

Comment: Can you/someone please add a thorough example where an existing RSA Key is imported to jwcrypto? I have been trying but keep getting errors.

Comment: The jose library does not support python 3. see https://github.com/Demonware/jose/pull/15 . Confusingly, another library called python-jose does not support JWE.

Comment: @kilokahn three years later, but since I had the same question; you can use `key = jwcrypto.jwk.JWK.from_pem(pemfile.read())`, as documented here: https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/stable/jwk.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

I can add a new library to the above suggested libraries, named [`jwskate`](https://pypi.org/project/jwskate/), as initials of "JSON Web Signing, Keys, Algorithms, Tokens, and Encryption". Disclaimer: I am the author of that lib. I wrote it because I was not satisfied with the APIs from the previous libs which are not Pythonic enough for my tastes.

Here is an usage example to encode/decode a JWE, in this particular case using `ECDH-ES+A256KW` and `A128CBC-HS256`, but obviously you can use any supported key management and encryption algorithm:

```
from jwskate import JweCompact, Jwk

plaintext = b"this is an example plaintext"

# I'll use this specific Elliptic Curve private key:
key = Jwk(
    {'kid': '8-nLgBsa-vXI_geoGt061_ZiVZ8BB-hYBDSoOQj9QgI',
     'alg': 'ECDH-ES+A256KW',
     'crv': 'P-256',
     'd': '39QMopTVL1u267FOx4ayvsueDU317vHaq_z-PU_NioA',
     'kty': 'EC',
     'x': 'f_VRZlIk1Qd2eNGFVas9sNXx9wd43L8VymknAyP5Ntk',
     'y': 'NmsfCs5VVOk6FEE31aaN9jB8rlfz1MWolBC3af_8DGs'}
)


# alternatively, you can generate one like this:
random_key = Jwk.generate_for_alg("ECDH-ES+A256KW").with_kid_thumbprint()

# sign your JWE
jwe = JweCompact.encrypt(plaintext, jwk=key.public_jwk(), enc="A128CBC-HS256")
print(jwe)
# it will look like: 
# eyJlcGsiOnsia3R5IjoiRUMiLCJjcnYiOiJQLTI1NiIsIngiOiItVnNfYkdSNTdUUVY4MHNnUENwcWZhVjNmWXR4dWdTWmJRM1FLeTJEVDdNIiwieSI6IjBtc0pZSUFfMC1OY2lfM0plOWZLSml3RU1ZdGRBaE9kZDZhdkp5THd0dzQifSwiYWxnIjoiRUNESC1FUytBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiOC1uTGdCc2EtdlhJX2dlb0d0MDYxX1ppVlo4QkItaFlCRFNvT1FqOVFnSSJ9.nnOEhmdonA19LRvyKSrL7f8aEb2vVwE7EU-zO91fyTUls4otMVppYg.h8h7Mxz4irvckPnknsnM0g.sRQJJq-RmiF7GeqvL8EpWTstS-daLbfgGnOPybWeOj8.z3heCfTiI0cjw8GaV0qcHw


# as recipient, you can decrypt your JWE like this:
jwe = JweCompact("""eyJlcGsiOnsia3R5IjoiRUMiLCJjcnYiOiJQLTI1NiIsIngiOiJkSllwMHNTZUVhMnhiMkc4M2Jnam
1VNnp4OEFxTkZRVmlJclJXUnlJYURzIiwieSI6InJXcEZ0OENESGNkQXFoMVR2eG9BZTFCT3FfZ2I3RzJya0hVd0hhNldfV0kif
SwiYWxnIjoiRUNESC1FUytBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiOC1uTGdCc2EtdlhJX2dlb0d0MDYx
X1ppVlo4QkItaFlCRFNvT1FqOVFnSSJ9.Nt89wpmYDZmbmjQCEZnZOygTOP5x2s7trvzLFehw1I_lMzTU-qlrcg.SQgJPG_WNUn
F13XnCJMAtw.wWwu_VUG7LPbsnWFTv-rAyiG84RW4tszR2fQ-AQaLBI.Onf3K4MSKhXaUrS8NpMDIA""")
assert jwe.decrypt(key) == plaintext
```

Answer (score -1):

https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwk.html#examples

```
from jwcrypto import jwk
_k = jwk.JWK.generate(kty='RSA', size=2048)
_text = _k.export()

import json
# loading the key back
_import_key_dict = json.loads(_text)
key = jwk.JWK(**json.loads(_import_key_dict))
```

Comment: You got your modules confused here; this is a demo of JWK key creation, and saving / loading. JWK is *not necessary to created and decrypt JWT encrypted tokens  with JWE*.